# Is there any open source Exchange server?

Tags: exchange, open-source

Is there any open source Exchange server that is work fine like Microsoft Exchange for Linux or Windows?

Comment: As time moved on, questions like this are no-longer considered topical. Specifically, product recommendation questions, including OSS alternatives recon, is considered off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) is an open source alternative to Microsoft Exchange. It uses a number of open source products, namely Postfix, Tomcat and OpenLdap. It can interact with Active Directory and other directory structures. It also offers a pretty extensive AJAX enabled web interface.

It offers most of the features offered by Exchange:

- Email
- Contacts
- Shared Calendaring
- VOIP integration
- Mobile access with activesync push sync and Blackberry Enterprise Server connector
- MAPI, IMAP, POP, iCal iSync Access
- Extensive web interface

It offers both an open source and commercial version, and is now owned by Yahoo.

Comment: Do you still recommend this, 3 years later? Thx

Answer (score 13):

Ahh...the white whale of open source, the [Exchange killer](http://theessentialexchange.com/blogs/michael/archive/2009/01/06/exchange-2007-and-windows-2008-offline-exchange-backup.aspx). There's no shortage of competitors:

- [SoGO](http://www.scalableogo.org/english.html)
- [Open-XChange](http://www.open-xchange.com/)
- [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/)
- [Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php)
- [Bongo](http://www.bongo-project.org/Main_Page)
- [Horde](http://www.horde.org/projects.php)
- [@Mail](http://atmail.com/)
- [Meldware](http://www.buni.org/mediawiki/index.php/Meldware_Communications_Suite)
- [OpenChange](http://www.openchange.org/)
- [Scalix](http://www.scalix.com/)
- [eGroupWare](http://www.egroupware.org/)
- [phpGroupWare](http://phpgroupware.org/)

And, for those that aren't necessarily looking for free (in either sense), but just don't like Microsoft or Exchange:

- [Gordano](http://www.gordano.com/)
- [PostPath](http://www.linuxtoday.com/news_story.php3?ltsn=2008-08-29-031-35-OS-OO) (once [Cisco](http://www.postpath.com/) decides what to do with it)
- [Lotus Domino/Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/domino/)
- [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html)
- [Kerio KMS](http://www.kerio.com/kms_home.html)
- [GroupWise](http://www.novell.com/products/groupwise/)

Comment: PostPath is (as far as I know) the closest you'll get to a "drop-in" replacement for Exchange; but it sounds like Cisco has spirited it away to the dungeons beneath their offices.  Scalix is based on HP OpenMail (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_OpenMail).

Comment: Heck, GroupWise even has BlackBerry support. Though you'll need a Windows server to run the BES.

Answer (score 6):

There is an Exchange-like open source project called [Open-Xchange](http://www.open-xchange.com/).

It is a messaging and collaboration platform combining common free software packages, open standards and web services. Open-Xchange Server is available as proprietary software and as a community supported open-source software (GPL 2) package.

Answer (score 3):

See [this article](http://linux.slashdot.org/linux/08/09/19/2023252.shtml) about Zafara groupware.

Answer (score 3):

We evaluated http://www.kerio.com/ when we moved away from Exchange 5.5, and it seemed quite polished.

Comment: +1 for Kerio.  We use it with Entourage client or Mail.app on our macs, and even have over-the-air email/cal/address push to our Nokia and iPhone mobiles.  Works great, and integrates with our OpenDirectory for users, groups, and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It is not open source, but the [community edition of Scalix](http://www.scalix.com/community/communityedition/index.php) is free-as-in-beer.  Never used it myself but I've heard really good things about it.

Comment: According to this, most of it is: http://www.scalix.com/community/opensource/

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it personally but take a look at http://www.zimbra.com/

It's dual licensed but the opensource one might give you everything you need.